# How to parse css for whois result?

Tags: php, whois

I am using whoislookupscript.com script for whois look up, i want to style each section differently eg.Registrar, Registrant, Admin, tech so that my viewers can get a idea of separation and looking to filter Registrant email id.

I really don't know how to started, if somebody can give any starter so that i can develope it.

Currently its plain text checkout here whoislookupscript . com

```
Response from the WHOIS server (whois.tucows.com):

Domain Name: BBC.COM
Registry Domain ID: 4794897_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.tucows.com
Registrar URL: http://tucowsdomains.com
Updated Date: 2014-06-15T05:05:24Z
Creation Date: 1989-07-15T04:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2015-07-14T04:00:00Z
Registrar: TUCOWS, INC.
Registrar IANA ID: 69
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: domainabuse@tucows.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.4165350123
Reseller: BBC Internet Services
Reseller: hostmaster@bbc.co.uk
Reseller: +44 1737 839592
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: Brandon Butterworth
Registrant Organization: British Broadcasting Corporation
Registrant Street: Broadcasting House Portland Place
Registrant City: London
Registrant State/Province: 
Registrant Postal Code: W1A 1AA
Registrant Country: GB
Registrant Phone: +44.3030409777
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: 
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: hostmaster@bbc.co.uk
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: Brandon Butterworth
Admin Organization: British Broadcasting Corporation
Admin Street: Broadcasting House Portland Place
Admin City: London
Admin State/Province: 
Admin Postal Code: W1A 1AA
Admin Country: GB
Admin Phone: +44.3030409777
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: 
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: hostmaster@bbc.co.uk
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: Brandon Butterworth
Tech Organization: British Broadcasting Corporation
Tech Street: Broadcasting House Portland Place
Tech City: London
Tech State/Province: 
Tech Postal Code: W1A 1AA
Tech Country: GB
Tech Phone: +44.3030409777
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: 
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: hostmaster@bbc.co.uk
Name Server: NS1.RBSOV.BBC.CO.UK
Name Server: NS1.THDOW.BBC.CO.UK
Name Server: NS1.TCAMS.BBC.CO.UK
DNSSEC: Unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2014-06-15T05:05:24Z <<<

Registration Service Provider:
BBC Internet Services, hostmaster@bbc.co.uk
+44 1737 839592
This company may be contacted for domain login/passwords,
DNS/Nameserver changes, and general domain support questions.

The Data in the Tucows Registrar WHOIS database is provided to you by Tucows
for information purposes only, and may be used to assist you in obtaining
information about or related to a domain name's registration record.

Tucows makes this information available "as is," and does not guarantee its
accuracy.
```

Comment: Is this taken via Linux prompt ? Show your code

Comment: Take each line to an array. Sort it by the first 5 letters. Then put them to a div. PS: Its a very dirty programming needed. But its a simple implementation. I dont have time to code to test it. Just leaving office ;)

Comment: here is the coding http://pastebin.com/87e8e4VM

Comment: Style with? photoshop? css? and from where is it taken?

Comment: @Abhinav Gauniyal the code is taken form whoislookupscript.com and i have also pasted it pastbin  pastebin.com/87e8e4VM .. i have explained it clearly in my question

Comment: I guess then styling refers to using css. The link you posted has several styles mentioned (starting from line 144 ) , apart from them , surround each information blocks into divs with classes and apply a stylesheet. Requirements are still not clear IMO.

Comment: @Abhinav Gauniyal its just resembles because its in code format, if you to want see the real output checkout here **http://whoislookupscript.com/demo.php**

Comment: @all Any idea how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once u get your output from whois records 
try with

```
  echo '<pre class="whois">';
    print "<div class=\"response_display\">Response from the WHOIS server ($whois_server):<br><br>".str_replace("\n","<br /><br />",$result)."</div>";

         echo '</pre>';
```

becoz sometimes developer think the that there are not getting \n so try the above one and you will be replaced with break after that you can go head with this answer

[How to split string from meshed content and add html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446723/how-to-split-string-from-meshed-content-and-add-html-element)